# Bootstrap working on Local Host but not on online server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code was working perfectly on local host with xampp. All I've done is upload it to a server and now it's not working. 
I uploaded all the BS files as well. I also fixed the href links to be '..../js/bootstrap.min.js' etc. No images load and nor does bootstrap I do not think. The reason I think the problem comes from Bootstrap is because all the text/buttons still appear, they just aren't customised with the css/JS as BS does.
They are php files.

This is a link to the site: http://www.johnnythyroid.com.
I'm only new and this is just for learning so all advice is much appreciated.

This is the relevant code I think, I deleted a lot of the stupid text to make it shorter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Jod</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap --> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/css/custom icons.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
    
  
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only"> Navbar toggle </span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/dansite1.php">Some Name</a>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"  style="line-height:21px; height:140px;"> <!-- added this to prevent change of navbar height when switching between login/logout screens --> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="active"><a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/dansite1.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/About.php">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown-header"></li>
       <li><a href="#accountLogin" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
       <li><a href="#accountCreate" data-toggle="modal">Create Account</a></li>
       <!-- <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class="dropdown-header">Portfolio</li>
       <li><a href="#">Portfolio 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Portfolio 2</a></li>  add divider to split up a drop down menu -->
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="navbar-text pull-right signedin"> Welcome, Guest! </li>    
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
   <h1> The </h1>
   <p> A simgn </p> 
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"> Bg </a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"> ng</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row-same-height">
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- works on a 12 point grid system - columns need to add up to 12 in a row-->
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/rocket.php" class="thumbnail home-thumb">
      <img src="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/first rocket.jpg" style="max-height:250px" alt="First rocket theme"/>
     </a>
     <h3> Rjj </h3>
     <p>sum dolor sit amet.</p> 
    </p>
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/rocket.php" class="btn btn-danger">View more</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- works on a 12 point grid system - columns need to add up to 12 in a row-->
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/stars.php" class="thumbnail home-thumb">
      <img src="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/sky.jpg" style="max-height:250px" alt="sky theme"/>
     </a>
     <h3> Ss </h3>
     <p>Lorenim.</p> 
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/stars.php" class="btn btn-danger">View more</a> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- works on a 12 point grid system - columns need to add up to 12 in a row-->
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/sky.php" class="thumbnail home-thumb">
      <img src="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/stars.jpg"  style="min-height:227px" alt = "Star theme"/>
     </a>
     <h3> y </h3>
     <p>Lorenim.</p> 
     <a href="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/sky.php" class="btn btn-danger">View more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
    <p> aaaaaa </p>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Am I seeing this right? It looks like there is an  entire html document in bootstrap.min.js: http://www.johnnythyroid.com/johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
change

```
<img src="johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/first rocket.jpg" style="max-height:250px" alt="First rocket theme">
```

into

```
<img src="http://johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/first rocket.jpg" style="max-height:250px" alt="First rocket theme">
```

add http:// to your all images src

Comment: FYI, `<img src="//johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/first rocket.jpg" style="max-height:250px" alt="First rocket theme">` will work as well. I would go with the relative path instead of absolute path..

Answer (score 2):

> Check the `console` for errors.

It says, **Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**, As I could see, You have included it and it is loaded correctly. Include that file before including *bootstrap.min.js*

Also correct that path of images. Your request url becomes: `http://www.johnnythyroid.com/johnnythyroidcom.ipage.com/Img/first%20rocket.jpg` which is incorrect.

*Note:* Just a blind guess, Incorrect path could be because of `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks a lot Rayon. I honestly did not know about the console way for checking errors. For anyone else looking on you just press f12 I believe.
The issue was in the way I was linking by the way, which both you and Saranga pointed out. Saranga's fix is correct, just add: 'http://' to the link. This had to be done for all my of my href not just the img src. Dunno if that makes sense but it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

when reffering 3rd party include css or jss
you have to use https if your server is using https
else use http
for example you are accessing your site http://yoursite.com or http://localhost
then http://getbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap.min.js or css will work
that is why it works on localhost
but if you use https for yoru site  https://yoursidte.com
then http://getbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap.min.js or css will not work
you will have to user https
e.g  https://getbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap.min.js or css

THIS WAS THE CASE WHY MY menu were wroking on localcomputer but not over https , after changing from http to https://getbootstrap.com/css/bootstrap.min.js or css now it is working ..
all these files can be in different locations
for example you may save bootstrap.min.css in your site folder in case you edited that file ..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).